# uWSGI will not restart after Harakiri

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a nginx + uWSGI + django app that runs on Ubuntu. I have enabled Harakiri. When running a long request which triggers the Harakiri the system can't restart and I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. When checking the uwsgi log I can see the following entry:

```
probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address (127.0.0.1:8000).
bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 779]
```

Here is my uwsgi config:

```
    --socket 127.0.0.1:8000 \
    --chdir /dir/to/app/ \
    --harakiri 180 \
    --max-requests 2000 \
    --module app.wsgi \
    --limit-as 512 \
    --reload-on-as \
    --reload-on-rss \
    --reload-mercy 8 \
    --http-timeout 180 \
    --disable-logging \
    --ignore-write-errors \
    --ignore-sigpipe \
    --logto /var/log/uwsgi.log \
    --die-on-term
```

What could cause this error? I can't see any conflicting processes running and if I restart the service manually, it works fine.

Here is the log entry

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0 (64bit) on [Wed Jan 22 16:44:07 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.3 on 14 January 2014 14:56:04
os: Linux-2.6.32-308-ec2 #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 16 15:25:39 UTC 2010
nodename: xxxxx.com (removed intentionally)
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 3
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7732
limiting address space of processes...
your process address space limit is 536870912 bytes (512 MB)
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be    
rejected on post-unbuffered webservers ***
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address (127.0.0.1:8000).
bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 779]
```

Comment: it looks like you do not have the master running

Comment: That didn't help. I still have the same problem. Once the Harakiri is triggered I can't start uwsgi and I see the same error in the logs.

Comment: please report full uwsgi logs, when harakiri is triggered a lot of things happens, but harakiri only kills workers not the master so your app will not be reloaded

Comment: this is the log after the harakiri, you should post the one before (when the harakiri happens)

Comment: The only thing else in the log is 

IOError: write error
F*CK !!! i must kill myself (pid: 26510 app_id: 0)...
*** if you want your workers to be automatically respawned consider enabling the
 uWSGI master process ***

Comment: well the log is clearly stating that you have not enabled the master. Your command line must have --master

Comment: Hm, strange. I did add it to the config file and restarted the service. Anyway I have now made sure that the master is enabled. Thanks for your help!